# Clicking on Social Tags in SharePoint 2013 redirecting to Profile Edit Page?

Tags: 2013, mysite, tags

I am in SP2013,I having Mysite with tag's,when i am clicking on the tag count it was redirecting to the MySite Profile Edit Page,can any one help on this,how it will work exactly when we click on the tags count.

[image]

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: any help on this.